# ReactFire isn't loading data from Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, reactfire

I have a Firebase project with a realtime database which contains a few test items, in this structure:

```
project-21093
|_items
  |_item1
    |_name: "Name"
    |_category: "Category"
  |_item2
    |_name: "Name2"
    |_category: "Category:
```

My `index.html` file includes the `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.3.0/firebase.js"></script>` tag, and this is my index.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
require("firebase/auth");
require("firebase/database");
import ReactFireMixin from 'reactfire';
require("./styles/customisations.scss");

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  apiKey: "key",
  authDomain: "auth",
  databaseURL: "url",
  storageBucket: "storage",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var App = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactFireMixin],

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      items: []
    };
  },

  componentWillMount: function() {
    var fireRef = firebase.database().ref("items");
    this.bindAsArray(fireRef, "items");
  },

  render: function() {}
})
```

The whole `config` section was taken directly from what the project page gave me. It didn't work in `index.html` as was instructed, so I loaded it here. I'm not sure which requirements exactly were needed so I loaded a bunch.

My problem is that `this.state.items` is always empty, despite having items in my realtime database, which I assume are meant to be bound to the `this.state.items` array in `componentWillMount`. Since the docs never specify what parameter needs to be passed in to the `firebase.database().ref()` call, I've tried everything from `project/items`, `project-21093/items` and variations to `database/data/items` with no success. The React plugin of Chrome dev tools clearly shows me the empty array. What am I missing to load this data successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that in the 'Rules' section of the 'Realtime Database' tab, I needed to change the rules a bit:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

With `.read` set to `"auth != null"` I couldn't access anything, changing it to `true` finally lets me get my data. Nowhere in any of the startup docs was this mentioned, so it wasn't until I saw [this Firecast video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1D0_wFlXgo&index=8&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLmnJ_FpMOZgyg6XcIGBu2OX) that I knew what to do. I'm still unsure how I'm going to configure this for proper web usage, but at least I can make my app with some data now.